# You can show that $f:\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ given by $f(1,n) = 2n-1$ and $f(m+1,n) = 2^m (2n-1)$ is a bijection.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics

We must first prove that $f(1,n) = 2n-1$ is a bijection. Suppose that $f(1,x)=f(1,y)$, this means that 
\begin{align}
    2x-1=2y-1 \\
    2x=2y \\
    x=y
\end{align}
We have therefore proven that it invective. Now we must show that it is surjective.
We can find $x \in N$ such that $f(x)=n$ where $x=\frac{n-1}{2}$
\begin{align}
   f(x)&=2\frac{n-1}{2}+1\\
   &=n-1+1 \\
   &=n
\end{align}
Therefore we have proven that it is surjective.

Now we must prove that $f(m+1,n) = 2^m (2n-1)$ is a bijection. Suppose that $f(x,y)=f(z,r)$, we have that 
\begin{align}
    2^x(2y-1)=2^z(2r-1)
\end{align}
Since $(2y-1)$ and $(2r-1)$ are odd, we must have that $a=c$ due to unique factorization. This is due to the fact that the power of $2$ dividing either side must be the same. Hence, $a=b$ by algebraic manipulation it is easy to see that $y=r$. We can conclude that $f$ is injective.

Hello, could some of y'all help me with this proof? 
I don't know if my injective proofs are:
1)necessary
2)well written

Furthermore, I have no idea on how to do the surjective proof. I have read the proof for similar questions already but I am do not see how to apply it correctly to this exercise.

Thanks

Comment: The function is surjective because every number is either odd in which case it gets hit by $f(1,n)$ or it is even, in which case it can be factored uniquely as a power of 2 times an odd number, so it gets hit by $f(m+1, n)$. It's injective since the factorizations are unique for evens and $f(1,n)$ is a bijection between $1\times\mathbb{N}$ and the odds.

Comment: The parts about the factorizations follows from the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof for the first function $(1,n)\mapsto 2n-1$ being injective looks good. For surjectivity, notice that $\frac{n-1}{2}$ need not be an integer. The map is only surjective onto the odd integers.

I'm not sure about your proof for injectivity in the second part. In particular, what are $a,b$ and $c$?

---

My suggestion for the second part is as follows. Any positive integer $j$ can be uniquely written as $j=2^nk$ where $n\geq 0$ and $k$ is odd (indeed, we just factor out "as many $2$'s" as possible, and the remaining factor is odd). Thus, the map $f$ is surjective since we have $f(n+1,k')=j$ where $k=2k'-1$ for a unique $k'\in\mathbb N$ by definition of odd. Injectivity of $f$ follows from the uniqueness of the expression.